# How do I make sure that radiobuttons arent clickable if the checkbox is unchecked in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, checkbox, radio-button, onclicklistener, radio-group

I'm practicing an exercise from a book, and it's asking me to first, create a checkbox and then three radiobuttons. If the checkbox is unchecked, then the radiobuttons should appear to be disabled/grey/unclickable. However, as soon as you check the checkbox, the radiobuttons should appear to be working and clickable.
I created the layout for both the checkbox and the radiobuttons (radiobuttons are a part of radiogroup) but I'm having troubling connecting them in the way the exercise is asking.
How would I go about writing this out in the mainactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if statement for check your checkbox is already click or not. Set your button in condition disabled/grey first after that use if statement for check your checkbox, if checkbox have clicked usable your button.

your code will look like this

```
Button button1, button2, button3;
Checkbox checkbox;

button1 = findViewById (yourid);
button2 = findViewById (yourid);
button3 = findViewById (yourid);
checkbox = findViewById (yourid);

//Disable your button first
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);

if(checkbox.isChecked()){
  button1.setEnabled(true);
  button2.setEnabled(true);
  button3.setEnabled(true);
 }
else{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkbox Haven't clicked", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for replying! I've tried doing that but it's not working. I can check the checkbox but the radiogroup is disabled - I see it but can't click it, regardless of whether or not the checkbox is checked

Comment: Is layout for radiogroup in mainactivity xml or different layout?

Comment: it is, I checked and each radiobutton was set on "android:enabled="false"". I removed it and tried running your code again but now the radiogroup is always enabled and I can click it even without checking the checkbox

Comment: Already edit my code, try it again

Comment: still nothing, I only got it to work they setVisibility instead of setEnabled. I don't why it doesn't work. visibility removes it completely but disabling it doesn't work at all. thank you for your help tho!